# set the spacing for bibliography

Tags: bibtex, line-spacing

Entire document is double-spaced but the bibliography should be single-spaced. However, my definition made the bibliography double-spaced too. Can anyone help how can I make only the bibliography a single spaced content ?

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\makeatother
Thanks
```

Comment: How do you set the double spacing for the document as a whole? Can you reverse that for the bibliography?

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Do you use the [setspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package?

Comment: Document class is report. The spacing is defined in the style with [setspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace). I also tried to set the space for bibliography but no change. I am sorry for the delay.